# How do i get a specific value from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a function that recieves two files .txt, one with tasks and another one with transaltors.
Returns a list of assigned tasks to the translators.

Anyway thats not the point, Im trying to check if a given value on the translators dictionary is equal to another element present in the tasks file which is a list, this is the function btw:

```
def scheduleTasks(translators, tasks, date, hour, periodAfter):

    """Assigns translation tasks to translators.

    Requires:
    translators is a dict with a structure as in the output of
    readingFromFiles.readTranslatorsFile concerning the update time; 
    tasks is a list with the structure as in the output of 
    readingFromFiles.readTasksFile concerning the period of
    periodAfter minutes immediately after the update time of translators;
    date is string in format DD:MM:YYYY with the update time;
    hour is string in format HH:MN: with the update hour;
    periodAfter is a int with the number of minutes of a period 
    of time elapsed.
    Ensures:
    a list of translation tasks assigned according to the conditions
    indicated in the general specification (omitted here for 
    the sake of readability).
    """
```

My problem is how do I get the value from the dictionary, I know d.values() but this returns all the values like (this is the value from one key, just as an example) :

```
[' (portuguese; french)', ' (english)', ' 3*', ' 0.803', ' 3000', ' 25000', ' 3084', ' 08:11:2016\\n']
```

, but i just want the (portuguese; french) bit, if a try to run something like

```
for translator in translators.values():
      print translator[0]
```

It returns '[' , Im not sure but I think this is due to how linux writes files, this is the function im using to read the file:

```
def readTranslatorsFile(file_name):
    """Reads a file with a list of translators into a collection.

    Requires:
    file_name is str with the name of a .txt file containing
    a list of translators organized as in the examples provided in
    the general specification (omitted here for the sake of readability).
    Ensures:
    dict where each item corresponds to a translator listed in
    file with name file_name, a key is the string with the name of a translator,
    and a value is the list with the other elements belonging to that
    translator, in the order provided in the lines of the file.
    """
    inFile = removeHeader(file_name)       

    translatorDict = {}
    for line in inFile:

        key = line.split(",")[INDEXTranslatorName]
        value = line.split(",")[1::]
        translatorDict[key] = str(value)
    return translatorDict
```

And this is the input file:

```
Company:
ReBaBel
Day:
07:11:2016
Time:
23:55
Translators:
Ana Tavares, (english), (portuguese), 1*, 0.501, 2000, 20000, 2304, 08:11:2016
Mikolás Janota, (czech), (english; portuguese), 3*, 1.780, 2000, 200000, 4235, 08:11:2016
Paula Guerreiro, (french), (portuguese), 2*, 0.900, 3500, 45000, 21689, 11:11:2016
Peter Wittenburg, (dutch; english), (dutch; english), 2*, 1.023, 2500, 20000, 7544, 08:11:2016
Rita Carvalho, (english), (portuguese), 1*, 0.633, 5000, 400000, 18023, 09:11:2016
Steven Neale, (portuguese; french), (english), 3*, 0.803, 3000, 25000, 3084, 08:11:2016
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i know still it gives me that output and just want part of the value.

Comment: try `list(translators.values())[0]` or `next(translators.values().__iter__())`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre first one returns [ in one line and ] on the next; the second one it's just blank lines

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you parse your file you create a list using `str.split()` which is good, but then you convert back this list as string, instead of preserving the `list` as your values. That is bad.

```
translatorDict[key] = str(value)
```

I would do that:

- split the line
- discard the headers (not enough fields: list index out of range)
- store the dictionary values as the list of tokens, much more flexible

code:

```
def readTranslatorsFile(file_name):

    inFile = removeHeader(file_name)       

    translatorDict = {}
    for line in inFile:
        tokens = line.split(",")  # split once and for good
        if len(tokens)>1:
          key = tokens[INDEXTranslatorName]
          value = tokens[1:]  # all items but first
          translatorDict[key] = value
    return translatorDict
```

(or use the `csv` module to handle comma-separated files more properly (quoting, etc))

Note that if `INDEXTranslatorName` is not zero, your method fails, then you could write `value = tokens[:INDEXTranslatorName]+tokens[INDEXTranslatorName+1:]` or `tokens.pop(INDEXTranslatorName)`

Then:

```
for translator in translators.values():
      print(translator[0].strip().replace(")","").replace("(",""))
```

efficiently prints your language tuples.

Comment: Thats what i though, since the output was a list with strings of those values that why when i was trying to print something from there it was giving me things like ' or just [

Comment: when i try the for loop it gives me index out of range o.o

Comment: But if i just print translator it gives me lists with the values inside, so I have no idea why [0] gives me index out of range

Comment: must be because of the header. Code edited to filter the header.

Comment: Yea, that was it, if i want a comparation between those languages and the ones on the task file, how can i remove the () on the languages since or filter them since the ones that i get from tasks.txt don't have them

Comment: see the `print` loop: strip spaces and remove parentheses. If you want to create a list instead of semi-colon separated, tell me.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but, you don't have any idea how should i start, this function? I have Two for loops one inside another one that run thru the languages and check for matches, but when it goes to the one that as two parameters, since its not exacly equal it doesn't return it.